# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre pretérito anterior y pretérito simple?

Tags: tiempos-verbales, pretérito

Necesito saber en qué se diferencia el Pretérito anterior del Pretérito simple.

¿En estas oraciones hay alguna diferencia?

> Ella comió
>
> Ella hubo comido

¿Hay diferencia entre pretérito anterior y pretérito simple?

Comment: Hola Natalia, bienvenida a [Spanish.se]. Oye, si coges un verbo cualquiera y lo conjugas en esos tiempos verbales, qué diferencias aprecias tú en las connotaciones o uso de cada uno? Tienes un par de ejemplos con esos tiempos en los que la diferencia no sea clara? Has consultado alguna fuente y hay algo específico que no entiendas? Así como has puesto la pregunta, parece que te estuviésemos haciendo los deberes. Es mejor plantear esto como las tutorías: revisa tú las reglas y pregunta por **algo específico**, o por lo menos añade ejemplos para clarificar y demostrar esfuerzo previo.

Comment: Lo siento no he sido específica.                                      
Mi duda es : si en estas oraciones hay alguna diferencia. Ella comió a decir Ella hubo comido, ¿Hay diferencia entre pretérito anterior y pretérito simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El pretérito perfecto simple denota simplemente una acción ocurrida en el pasado. Así, en

> Ella comió.

estamos diciendo que una persona, en un tiempo pretérito, realizó la acción de comer.

El que puede dar más problema es el pretérito anterior o antepretérito. Este segundo nombre ya denota que estamos hablando de una acción transcurrida inmediatamente antes que otra en el pasado. Este tiempo verbal se trata en la *Nueva gramática* en los [párrafos 23.16i y siguientes](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=OnhXQZgFwViNaHpk).

> El PRETÉRITO ANTERIOR (HUBE CANTADO) denota una situación pasada separada por un lapso breve de otra igualmente pretérita, como en *Algunos invitados se marcharon apenas hubo terminado la cena*, donde la noción de inmediatez está presente en el adverbio *apenas*.

La gramática explica que hay un uso antiguo del pretérito anterior, y que se registra a veces en textos contemporáneos (más en el español europeo que en el americano), según el cual los dos tiempos (anterior y perfecto simple) se asemejan. Cita como ejemplo el reglamento hipotecario:

> *Los gastos y costas del recurso deberán ser satisfechos por los interesados que lo hubieron promovido.*

Esta frase, en realidad, debería haber terminado con "que lo promovieron". Este uso en realidad es raro hoy día, encontrándose a veces en la lírica con intención arcaizante deliberada.

> En la lengua escrita del español contemporáneo [...] se usa hoy HUBE CANTADO con verbos télicos y precedido siempre de expresiones adverbiales o conjuntivas que expresan posterioridad. Las fundamentales son las siguientes: *apenas, así que, cuando, después (de) que, en cuanto, enseguida que, luego que, nada más, no bien, no más, tan pronto como* y *una vez (que)*. En todos estos casos alternan HUBE CANTADO y CANTÉ, con marcada preferencia en los textos por la segunda opción.

Esto quiere decir que incluso en los casos donde se puede usar el pretérito anterior, se prefiere usar el pretérito perfecto simple. Así, el ejemplo

> *Calló, para tomar un sorbo de agua. Pero, apenas lo hubo hecho [...], de manera totalmente abrupta se puso de pie y se despidió.* (Vargas Llosa, *Fiesta*.)

podría haberse perfectamente redactado con "apenas lo hizo".

Answer (score 4):

El pretérito anterior (también llamado el antepretérito) significa casi lo mismo que el pluscuamperfecto (también llamado el ante**co**pretérito).  En ambos, se hace una referencia a una acción que ocurrió *antes* de otra acción radicada en el tiempo pretérito.

El pretérito simple (o indefinido) es simplemente una acción que ocurrió en el pasado, que no hace referencia a otra acción (fuere del tiempo que fuere).

Entonces si decimos

> Ella comió.

Estamos contando algo que ocurrió en el pasado, específicamente algún acaecimiento aislado.  Si ponemos varios verbos en pretérito simple , podemos contemplarlos como acciones ordenadas:

> Ella comió, <sub>(y después)</sub> se duchó <sub>(y después)</sub> se acostó.

Tomemos esta acción de acostarse.  ¿Qué hizo ella antes de acostarse?  Si queremos enfatizar el hecho de hacer aquello antes de acostarse, podemos emplear el pretérito anterior o el pluscuamperfecto.

> Cuando ella por fin se acostó, ya había comido.
>   Se hubo duchado cuando se acostó.

Lo de *había comido* es lo normal en el español moderno (también es válida, aunque de poco uso hoy, la forma simple, *comiera*).  Cuando decimos que ella *había comido*, simplemente hacemos referencia al hecho de que en *algún* momento comió.  El pretérito anterior se diferencia del pluscuamperfecto en que representa una acción que, en tiempos cronológicos, viene justo antes de la acción posterior correspondiente.   Por tanto, no sería posible decir *hubo comido…* en el ejemplo porque entre lo de comer y lo de acostarse, realizó otra acción distinta.    Incluso si dijésemos *se había duchado*, no tenemos gran constancia de que pasara (o no) mucho tiempo entre la ducha y la entrada al sobre.  Pero con *se hubo duchado*, se supone que al terminar de ducharse, se fue efectivamente directamente a la cama.

Hoy en día, se está perdiendo la distinción y se emplea el pluscuamperfecto compuesto (había …<sup>-ado</sup>/<sub>-ido</sub>) para todo, usando en su caso adverbios como *de repente* o *justo después* para indicar la inmediatez de la acción posterior.